# Wildcard-querying an array with forward slash in the query

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

In my documents indexed by elasticsearch, I have a field called `IPC8s.IPC8` which is an array of strings, which can look like these :

```
["B63H011/00"]
["B60F3", "B60K1", "B60K17", "B60K17/23", "B60K6", "B60K6"]
["G06F017/00"]
etc...
```

(for anyone curious, these are CPC patent classification numbers)

I need to query this field with trailing wildcards. In other words, if I put in "B63H", the document containing "B63H011/00" should match. Same if I put in "B63H011/" or "B63H011/0".

I tried multiple queries, none of which worked :

```
{
  query_string: {
    default_field: "IPC8s.IPC8",
    query: "(B63H*) OR (B63H011/*)",
    analyze_wildcard: true
  }
}
```

I tried this one also with `\"B63H*\" OR \"B63H011/*\"`, doesn't work.

Then I tried :

```
[{
  wildcard: {
    "IPC8s.IPC8": { value: "B63H*" }
  }
},
{
  wildcard: {
    "IPC8s.IPC8": { value: "B63H011/*" }
  }
}]
```

This doesn't work either. I then tried escaping the "/" because it has to be taken literally. Didn't work.

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

**Edit** : Here is the mapping for that specific field :

```
"IPC8s": {
  "properties": {
    "IPC8": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my latest try that still didn't work (if I don't escape the forward slash, elasticsearch returns an error) :

```
{
  query_string: {
    default_field: "IPC8s.IPC8",
    query: "(B63H*) OR (B63H011\\/*)",
    analyze_wildcard: true,
    analyzer: "keyword"
  }
}
```

**Edit 2** : This seems to do the trick :

```
    {
      query_string: {
        default_field: "IPC8s.IPC8.keyword",
        query: "(B63H*) OR (B63H011\\/*)",
        analyze_wildcard: true,
        analyzer: "keyword"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text type with standard analyzer will create following token, hence you are not able to search on /

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "b63h011",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "00",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Create a subfield for IPC8 with type keyword, which will store text as it is

```
GET index21/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "IPC8s.IPC8.keyword": {
        "value": "B63H011/*"
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Actually I can't really change the elasticsearch configuration, it's on a distant server. Is there a way to use the keyword tokenizer "on the fly" while querying ?

Comment: Can you check your mapping, most of the time it is created by default. keyword tokenizer is the way data is stored in inverted index, change in mapping is required for it (if not present)

Comment: I think I got it (see edit). Thanks, your answer helped a lot.

Comment: Glad could be of help